# Can not access Windows 10 after Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 but am no longer able to access Windows when rebooting.  On start up my computer, which is booting through UEFI, goes straight to GRUB but there is no option to select the Windows OS.  There also does not seem to be an option for Windows when selecting from the boot menu.  The Windows files are still viewable in the partition I created before installing Ubuntu and Boot-Repair did not fix the problem. http://paste.ubuntu.com/14492546/ is the link Boot-Repair provided me.  Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: sudo update-grub solved the problem.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo update-grub`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can try.

First of all, run `sudo update-grub` and restart your computer.

If you still can't boot into Windows, try out the tool [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). You can install it in Ubuntu using the ppa mentioned in the second option. Run it, and it should bring back your Windows boot entry. If not, there is likely a problem with the Windows partitions.

Comment: sudo update-grub did the trick! Thank you guys so much!

Comment: also solved it for me after upgrade to ubuntu 22 10 :) 
"Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ..."